# Media file uploads go to /wp-content instead of /wp/wp-content in a subdirectory-installed instance of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

## Problem

Can't get Media upload files to drop into the right directory in a subdirectory-installed WordPress. What is the appropriate way to...

1. Correct the path problem for future uploads
2. Correct any pre-existing hard-coded references in the database with the wrong path

## Symptoms

- `wp-content` exists in both `/wp-content` and `/wp/wp-content`
- Uploads to the Media tab in WordPress go to `/wp-content/uploads/2018/06`
- Blank thumbnails are shown in the Media tab for images that all reference something like `/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/some_image_name.jpg`
- Drag and drop upload to the WordPress Media tab often results in `http error`

## Environment

- WordPress core and all files are installed in the `/wp` subdirectory
- Settings > WordPress Address (URL) = `https://www.example.com/wp`
- Settings > Site Address (URL) = `https://www.example.com/wp`
- The database row for `upload_path` (within `wp_options` table) = `/home/user/public_html/wp-content/uploads` (but want it in `wp` subdirecty)
- Web Hosting = GoDaddy Economy Linux Hosting with cPanel
- PHP version = 7.1
- memory_limit = 512M
- post_max_size = 128M
- upload_max_filesize = 1G
- Relavant PHP extensions enabled = imagick, gd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when this happens there's an absolute path that needs to be updated in the database. I found this out from this post...

http://kb.enoi.se/i-can-not-upload-images-to-my-wordpress-site-after-moving-it/

In short look in the `wp_options` table for and edit the row where the column name `option_name` = `upload_path`. Then change the `option_value` from the absolute path to have the correct subdirectory path. It will be something like...

`/home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads`

Change it to to have your correct subdirectory, in my case `wp`..

`/home/username/public_html/wp/wp-content/uploads`